# 2d-list with 2-tuples as indexes

Tags: r, list, data-structures

I'm pretty new to R, is there a way to have a two-dimensional list of two-tuples as indexes in R programming language?

For example :

```
my_list[(1,2)] 
#[1] 7, 10, 3
```

Comment: Could you provide further context and examples?

Comment: Very unclear. Please provide [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and expected output.

Comment: @snoram Actually, I'm trying to store adjacent vertices[k] for any two arbitrary vertices [v,u] such that k is connected to both v and u so I need a list that is indexed by two integers as vertex id's and a list for each tuple which is their common adjacent vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I cannot comment yet but it kind of sounds like you just mean a matrix.

Please write what exactly you want to achieve. In case you actually mean matrices it work like this:

You can define a matrix, e.g. a 3x3 matrix of numbers 1:9:

```
A = matrix(1:9, nrow=3, ncol=3)
```

Then reference the i-th row and j-th column by `A[i, j]`.

```
A[1, 3]
[1] 7
```

You can have any number of dimensions using `array`.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem using a different way but the difference between a matrix and the data structure that I described is that you can have a single value for each tuple in a matrix, but I needed a list of values for each tuple.

Comment: you mean a list object?(easy difference, one where you write the subscript with double brackets, `list[[i]]'). If you need a 2-touple to correspond to a vector, it sounds like a perfect job for a three-dimensional array.

Edit: I just read your other comment, so I suppose your lists would be of different length, and then indeed you might prefer a different solution.

Comment: Yeah, they're different in length.